# Access Value of variable content in twig template

Tags: theming, 8, debugging

I'm new in a Drupal 8 and using [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) `kint()` function for debugging. In my twig template `menu--main.html.twig`, I have looped for the menu items like this:-

`{% for item in items %}
   {{kint(item.url)}}`

The output like this:-

[image]

What I should write to print the URI, I've tried `{{item.url.uri}}` but not working

Comment: Do you try {{item.url.getUri}} ?

Comment: Just guessing, `{% if item.url.isExternal() %}foo{% endif %}`

Comment: Him want  get uri  of url not external :D

Comment: @MrD It's working fine, Thanks so much. but how I know that I have to write `getUri` to render it

Answer (score 1):

You can try `{{item.url.getUri}}`.

You can change to tab **Available methods** to see other method. Example isExternal. :D